# Can not push an array as a property of a two dimensional empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 $('#createFields').click(function () {

        for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfFields; i++) {

            fieldsArray[i] = {};
            console.log(fieldsArray);
        };

    });
```

i get the numberOfFields variable from a select box

```
$("body").on("change","input:checkbox",
    function () {

        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

            var val = $(this).prop('value');
            addColumns(val);

        }
        else {

            console.log("deleting...")
            singleArray=singleArray.splice(singleArray.length, newArray.length);
            InitData();
        }
    }
);
```

I call the addColumns function each time a checkbox is checked.

```
    function addColumns(val) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    newArray = [];
    str = [];

           str.push(val);

           var url = ListJoin.appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists/getbytitle('" + selectedList + "')/items?$select=" + str + "" +
                    "&@target='" + ListJoin.hostweburl + "'";

            ListJoin.executor.executeAsync({
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
                    var response = jsonObject.d.results;

                    for (var i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; i++) {
                        var tu = [];
                        var keys = Object.keys(response[i]);
                        //Skip keys[0] because it's always metadata
                        for (var j = 1; j < keys.length; j++) {
                            var key = keys[j];
                            var val = [response[i][key]];
                            console.log("bujar" + val);
                            newArray.push(val);

                        }
                    }

                   fieldsArray[1].push(newArray);
```

can not push neither concat newArray=['BBB','MMM','CCC'] to the an array of the fieldsArray array

```
                    InitData();
                    defer.resolve();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    defer.reject();
                }
            });
            return defer;

}
```

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: `fieldsArray[i] = {};` That is an `Object` not an `Array`. So `fieldsArray[1].push` will not work since `Object`s do not have a push method. Check your console for errors

Comment: I forgot to change that back to fieldArray[i]=[] ,i was trying both but none of them worked for me.

Comment: and i dont get any error, it is just not concatanating or pushing to that array.

Comment: @PatrickEvans i changed fieldArray to Array and tried with concat() and also changed another thing which i dont remember what it was and it worked.I fixed this at work thats why i couldnt remember imediatly.Thank you for your help,